# Writing data to completely separate locations simultaneously using update()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my firebase app when a new user signs up I add their initial data like displayname, emai , photourl  to the database under the top level `users` node. This works fine.

Now when a user post  a status, I want to upload the the post to top level `statuses` node where all  user statuses are kept. And simultaneously I want to upload the post to current  user's posts node i.e `users/currentuser/posts`.

I am following the methods shown on official firebase site [here.](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html)

The problem is when I hit the post button nothing happens and no data is posted to the database

My function that gets invoked when the post button is clicked:

```
function postStatus(){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("allstatuses");
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    var newStatusRef = ref.push();
    var newStatusKey = newStatusRef.key();

    var statusData = {
        status: postInput.val(),
        likes: 0,
        dislikes: 0
    };
    var updateUserStatus = {};
    updateUserStatus["users/" + user.uid + "/" + newStatusKey] = statusData;
    updateUserStatus["allstatuses/" + newStatusKey] = statusData;

    if(user){
        firebase.database().ref().update(updateUserStatus);
    }else{
        alert("please login");   
    }

}
```

What am  I doing wrong?

Comment: If you call `firebase.database().ref("allstatuses").child(ref.push().key).set(true)` does that write to the database successfully?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen where do you mean I shall call this?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yippeee,,, i solved the problem,, i posted thé answer,,anyways thankyou very much for helping

Comment: Ah... good one. I can't believe I overlooked that. Anyway: happy hacking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API reference [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#key) it is key not key()

**Change this**

```
var newStatusKey = newStatusRef.key();
```

**to**

```
var newStatusKey = newStatusRef.key;
```